# Pygame window keeps freezing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a small program in pygame, but it keeps freezing and saying "not responding", even hen the program is still running and calling the pygame.draw function.

```
 if timer==0:
    mouseMoved=False
    import ctypes
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
    true_res = (ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1))
    disp = pygame.display.set_mode(true_res,pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    del ctypes
    color=(0,0,0)
    pos=[50,60]
    pygame.Surface.fill(disp, (255,255,255))
    #mouse.move(mPos[0], mPos[1])
    firstMove=True
    x, y = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
    while not mouseMoved:
        #mouse.move(mPos[0], mPos[1])
        mouseMoved=False
        pMouse=mPos
        #print(pMouse)
        mPos=mouse.get_position()
        #print(pos)
        if pos[0]+4>=x:
            horiz=-1
            color=(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
        elif pos[0]-4<=0:
            horiz=1
            color=(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
        if pos[1]-4<=0:
            vert=1
            color=(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
        elif pos[1]+4>=y:
            vert=-1
            color=(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
        pos[0]+=horiz
        pos[1]+=vert
        #pygame.Surface.fill(disp, (250,250,250))
        pygame.draw.circle(disp, color, (pos[0], pos[1]), 9)
        pygame.display.update()
        #time.sleep(0.01)
        if not pMouse==mPos:
            if firstMove:
                firstMove=False
            else:
                timer = 360
                mouseMoved=True
                #pygame.display.iconify()
                #disp = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
                pygame.display.quit()
                #pygame.display.update()
                print(f"moved from {mPos} to {pMouse}")
```

This thing is supposed to run until the mouse moves when it removes the display.

Comment: You've to to handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) in the application loop.

Comment: as I know on Windows when you don't use `pygame.event` to get events from system then system things that program not responding. Besides if you don't get events then it doesn't know mouse position and `mouse.get_position()` may gives wrong results. The same problem can be with `pygame.key.get_pressed()` if you don't get events.

Answer (score 0):

In your main while loop, add something like this which should allow resizing and moving of the screen. It will depend on how you set up your original screen which we can't see or run from your code sample.

```
for event in pg.event.get():
    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
        pg.quit()
        quit()

    elif event.type == pg.VIDEORESIZE:
        self.height = event.h
        self.width = event.w
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pg.RESIZABLE)
```